# How to create 3 thread that will work one by one

Tags: java, multithreading

Is that possible to do without flags? I can use only notify/wait/synchronized.
I want to print: worker1 worker2 worker3 worker1 worker2... But I have a race condition for the wait()/notify() methods.

```
class ThirdWorker implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run(){
            for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
                synchronized (mutex3) {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " worker3 " + (i + 1));
                    try {
                        mutex3.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    synchronized (mutex) {
                        mutex.notify();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class SecondWorker implements Runnable{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (mutex) {
                new Thread(new ThirdWorker()).start();
            }
                for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
                    synchronized (mutex2) {
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " worker2 " + (i + 1));
                        synchronized (mutex3){
                            mutex3.notify();
                        }
                        try {
                            mutex2.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

            }
        }
    }

    class FirstWorker implements Runnable{ 
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (mutex) {
                new Thread(new SecondWorker()).start();
                for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " worker 1 " + (i+1));
                    try {
                        mutex.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    synchronized (mutex2){
                        mutex2.notify();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    new Thread(new FirstWorker()).start();
```

I know that it would be easy to do it with flags, but I can't.

Comment: It is possible but you need to provide more details such as when is each thread supposed to work, and perhaps doing what? By the way look into the java.util.concurrent package, there are many classes to handle what you want you do in an easier way. Also why is each thread starting the next one?

Comment: Why is each thread starting the next one? I want to start threads one by one. I thought this realisation was correctly.  I just want create 3 threads and each thread print her name. But this threads should be work one by one. First thread print: worker1, second thread print worker2 after first thread, third thread print worker3 after second thread. And all this work in a cycle.

Comment: Just a comment abt the code above. Getting a second monitor when you already have a first monitor can lead to deadlock. Imagine another thead that has the second monitor and is waiting for the first one, which is owned by the first thread which is waiting for the second one.

Comment: Re, "I want to start threads one by one."  If you want to perform a list of tasks, one-by-one, then the correct way to do it is to perform all of the tasks in a single thread.  There is no benefit to using multiple threads the way you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here there is an example of how you can do it.

**Note:**
The property `turnIsFor` is the protected resource.
The threads are created as siblings.
The object used as a monitor (`lock`) is not used for anything else but that.
There is a `while` wrapping the `lock.wait()` with the condition that should enable the thread to run.
Both, `lock` and `notify` have to be inside the `synchronized` block.
Also note that on purpose I started the threads in a random order and still they go one at a time in the expected order given by the shared property `nextTurnIsFor`.

```
public class ThreeThreads {

    Thread t1, t2, t3;
    Lock lock = new Lock();
    int turnIsFor = 1;
    public static void main(String ... args) {
        ThreeThreads threeThreads = new ThreeThreads();
        threeThreads.run();
    }

    public ThreeThreads() {


        Runnable printName1 = new Runnable() {

            int turn = 1;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true){
                    try {
                        synchronized(lock) {
                            while(turnIsFor != turn){
                                lock.wait();;
                            }
                            System.out.println( Thread.currentThread().getName());  
                            turnIsFor = 2;
                            lock.notifyAll();
                        }
                    }catch(Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        Runnable printName2 = new Runnable() {

            int turn = 2;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true) {
                    try {
                        synchronized(lock) {
                            while(turnIsFor != turn){
                                lock.wait();;
                            }
                            System.out.println( Thread.currentThread().getName());  
                            turnIsFor = 3;
                            lock.notifyAll();
                        }
                    }catch(Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        Runnable printName3 = new Runnable() {

            int turn = 3;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true) {
                    try {
                        synchronized(lock) {
                            while(turnIsFor != turn){
                                lock.wait();;
                            }
                            System.out.println( Thread.currentThread().getName());  
                            turnIsFor = 1;
                            lock.notifyAll();
                        }
                    }catch(Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        t1 = new Thread(printName1, "Thread 1");
        t2 = new Thread(printName2, "Thread 2");
        t3 = new Thread(printName3, "Thread 3");

    }

    public void run() {
        t3.start();
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }


    private static final class Lock{};

}
```

Comment: Oh... I think that "turnIsFor" and "turn" is the flag. I hope to solve this problem without flags. I am sorry that I did not duplicate my request twice in comments...

Comment: Implemented or not with a flag you need a condition to set when it is ok for a thread to run. lock.wait has to be in a while loop. Just replace the turnIsFor != turn with that condition and you are set.

Comment: You're right. Sorry it's to late that I can think normaly. Thanks!